# Layout. Two inline boxes with content where one is divided into other boxes

Tags: html, css, layout, inline

Desired result: The two divs with class `inline` should be on the same horizontal level (the second one contains two other divs with some content).

[image: vision of desirable result]

However, as can be seen below, the two divs are not aligned vertically. If I remove the content (the word "text") from both the `.inside` divs, they line up as expected.

How can I make them line up? What is causing this?

```css
.inline,
.inside {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
.inside {
  height: 48px;
  background-color: salmon;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
</div>

<div class="inline">
  <div class="inside">text</div>
  <div class="inside">text</div>
</div>

<hr>
<div>Without content (i.e. the word "text"):<div>
<div class="inline">
</div>

<div class="inline">
  <div class="inside"></div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `.inside` divs are the same width as the enclosing `.inline` div. This is why they're stacked. You need to change the widths.

Comment: And also ".inside" element should be inline-block, not ".inline" element.

Comment: Right, I was just about to add what @Dima said. Or float them.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I actually need them to be stacked (one inside div have to be one the top of the other one). Don't quite get why they need to be different widths...

Comment: Oleg, these comments indicate that your question isn't clear. A picture of what you want would help. But you might find your answer in one of the "Related" questions on the right of the page.

Comment: So you mean you want the `.inline` divs on the same level? I see. Yeah, your question is not clear.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's going on (something about the text nodes pushing things around) but you can either set the (second) `inline` div to `position: absolute` or `float: left`. Without seeing what else will be placed around these divs, it's hard to know exactly but this should work with some tweaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.inline {    
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Thanks everybody.